# omniauth-facebook-access-token not accepting JSON access_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, facebook, omniauth

I am trying to use omniauth-facebook-access-token along with my JSON-based API. The following is appearing in the log:

```
Started POST "/auth/facebook_access_token/callback" for 192.168.37.129 at 2013-09-23 14:57:34 -0400
(facebook_access_token) Callback phase initiated.

ArgumentError - No access token provided.:
  (gem) omniauth-facebook-access-token-0.1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook-access-token.rb:79:in `callback_phase'
  (gem) omniauth-1.1.4/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `callback_call'
```

I do see the access_token being provided inside of the request in

action_dispatch.request.request_parameters -> access_token

How can I prevent these lines from `omniauth-facebook-access-token-0.1.2.1/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook-access-token.rb` from failing?

```
 77       def callback_phase
 78         if !request.params['access_token'] || request.params['access_token'].to_s.empty?
 79           raise ArgumentError.new("No access token provided.")
 80         end
```